# 2 similar java enums and a method who decide from which enum should the value be chosen

Tags: java, string, enums

I want to implement a method who decide from what java enum to get a specific value. For example:

```
public enum Credentials1 {
    USERNAME("user"),
    PASSWORD("pass");
}
public enum Credentials2 {
    USERNAME("user"),
    PASSWORD("pass");
}
```

and then, in another class I want a generic method to decide, based on another param, what enum should I use to get the correct user. Something like:

```
public String decide(here I should pass something?) {
    switch (myParam) {
        case "1":
            return Credentials1.USERNAME;
        case "2":
            return Credentials2.USERNAME;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Can this be achievable, because I didn't succeed? And think that besides `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` I will have a lot of constants in those enums.

Comment: 1: What should your method `decide` return? "USERNAME" or "user"?

Comment: 2: What does the parameter within both enumerations mean?

Comment: `switch`is ok, but why would you do that if they have the same values?

Comment: what is the logic according to you like to select between the two?

Comment: I do not know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but this is not the way you should use enums. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for examples of how to use them. In the way your code is currently written down, the two credentials enums are completely unrelated. (By the way, the `switch` statement suggests that `myParam` is of type `String`.)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each enum class represents the credentials of some user? In that case, don't use enums but define a Credentials class and create an instance for each user.

Comment: yeah actually, just figure it out that all I want is a method which is returning an enum, In one case I want to return the first enum, in case 2 the second one.

Comment: Should that method return an enum (as you said in your comment) or a String (as you specified in your code)?

Comment: It should return an enum, not a String as I initially wrote. The method should only decide which enum should I use further in my code. I've succeed to make it work with an interface and then to implement a method for each constant from enum (here the methods are different only on enum constants returned), but is there any other solution to implement only one method for the entire enum and to return what I need?

Comment: Should it return an enum class or a specific value of a specific class? Explain better what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want an enum class, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a method that returns the desired enumeration class:

```
public Class<? extends Enum<?>> getEnum(int param)
{
  // Determine enumeration class based on specified parameter
  switch (param)
  {
    case 1:
      return (Enum1.class);
    case 2:
      return (Enum2.class);
    default:
      return (null);
  }

} // getEnum
```

Then create a method that returns the desired instance:

```
public Object getEnumInstance(Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz,
                              String                   name)
  throws Exception
{
  // Determine the 'valueOf()' method that creates an instance from a string
  // Every enumeration class has a static valueOf() method that expects a String as a parameter
  Method value_of_method;
  value_of_method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);

  // Get and return instance
  return (value_of_method.invoke(null, name));

} // getEnumInstance
```

Next, create a method that returns the value of the specified enum:

```
public String getEnumValue(Object enum_instance)
  throws Exception
{
  // Determine the 'getValue()' method of this enumeration instance
  // At least, I suppose the method is called like that in your enumeration classes
  // It doesn't want parameters and returns a String
  Method get_value_method;
  get_value_method = enum_instance.getClass().getMethod("getValue");

  // Return value of the enumeration instance
  return ((String)get_value_method.invoke(enum_instance));

} // getEnumValue
```

Finally, create a method that combines the whole stuff:

```
public String decide(int    param,
                     String enum_instance_name)
  throws Exception
{
  // Get correct enumeration class
  Class<? extends Enum<?>> enum_class;
  enum_class = getEnum(param);

  // Get correct instance
  Object enum_instance;
  enum_instance = getEnumInstance(enum_class, enum_instance_name);

  // Return its value
  return (getEnumValue(enum_instance));

} // decide
```

Now we can finally do what we have to do:

```
public void run()
  throws Exception
{
  // Get password of 2nd enum
  String result;
  result = decide(2, "PASSWORD");
  System.out.println(result);

  // Or username of 1st enum
  result = decide(1, "USERNAME");
  System.out.println(result);

} // run
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `Credentials` with the following method:

```
public interace Credentials {

    public String value();
}
```

Make these `enum`s to implement an interface with a common method returning the value. Below is `Credentials1`. The `Credentials2` is implemented analogically.

```
public enum Credentials1 implements Credentials {

    USERNAME("user"),
    PASSWORD("pass");

    private String value;

    Credentials1(String value) {
        this.value= value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

Here you pass the correct `enum` for the further processing:

```
public String decide(Credentials credentials) {
     return credentials.value();
}
```

A sample usage is:

```
String string = this.decide(Credentials1.USERNAME);
```

Comment: Yes, but this is similiar to what I post afterwards, as I will have to check every time what enum should I use, but I want to make this dynamically, at runtime and not to have for each constant from enum a method like if(something) decide(Credentials1.USERNAME); else decide(Credentials2.USERNAME);

Comment: What exactly are the checking conditions based on?

Comment: I should login with one or another account based on a parameter from a properties file in my project. Like if(gmailSite) return Credentials1.USERNAME.value() else return Credentials2.USERNAME.value(). But then I must choose from the same enum multiple values for some verifications